# Singleton contract using inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, singleton

I'm trying to create a framework where Singleton objects can get the core of their implementation from. The use for this is so if I make multiple Singleton classes, I don't need to re-write their (while simple) implementations over and over.

I tried this:

```
public abstract class Singleton
{
    protected static final Lock mutex = new ReentrantLock(true);
    // Not even subclasses are allowed to mess with `instance`.
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    // Here is the problem, static methods cannot be abstract.
    protected static abstract Singleton init();

    public static Singleton get()
    {
        mutex.lock();

        // The super class has no idea how to instantiate
        // this singleton, so let subclasses handle that
        // via the abstract init method
        if (instance == null)
            instance = init();

        mutex.unlock();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

But it really cannot work because the whole concept of `static` members with inheritance doesn't go well together.

My other option is to do:

```
public enum Singleton
{
    INSTANCE
}
```

But since `enum` cannot be extended, I cannot do:

```
public enum MySingleton extends Singleton
{
    // Member variables and functions here
    ...
}
```

I could have every implementation just be an `enum` and the only code I have to repeat (I think?) is INSTANCE unless I'm missing something? The only downside I see there is the Singleton is created at the beginning of the runtime and not on-demand later on in the program.

I could also do an interface but then I get stuck here:

```
public interface Singleton
{
    Singleton instance = null;

    default void set(Singleton s)
    {
        assert instance == null;
        assert s != null;
        // cannot do this, as `instance` is FINAL
        instance = s;
    }
}
```

What's the best way to do define a Singleton contract without having to retype the entire implementation over again?

Thanks

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel.  Can you not use Spring?

Comment: @JimGarrison What is Spring?

Comment: [Spring](https://spring.io/) is a framework. At its core it eliminates the need for implementing singletons by providing a standard way to wire together instances of cooperating classes dynamically, at runtime.  The singleton pattern is deprecated as it leads to brittle, hard-to-maintain code.  Spring can be overwhelming as it has grown to epic proportions, but if you stick to the simple basics it can help you a lot, rather quickly.  There is a learning curve but it's well worth it for any system larger than something you write for yourself only.

Comment: @JimGarrison I try and stay away from frameworks as much as I can because they simply make things easier and dampen learning potential of lower level concepts. I will check it out though. Still, this does not really solve my problem.